# OpenCL programming in Charm++

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, cluster-computing, charm++

Is it possible to run OpenCL through Charm++, while retaining the same fault tolerance and load balancing capabilities as for CPU or CUDA?

I did not explicitly see anything mentioned in the tutorials or the book.

Answer (score 0):

Background: I'm one of the core developers of Charm++.

It's not clear whether you mean compiling OpenCL code to a Charm++-based parallel program, or calling kernels written in OpenCL from Charm++ code. Regardless, there is nothing explicitly implemented to support either of those cases at present.

Compiling OpenCL to Charm++ would be a large project. I don't know of anyone proposing to do such a thing, but it's not fundamentally implausible.

The research group behind Charm++, the [Parallel Programming Laboratory](https://ppl.cs.illinois.edu) has looked at the possibility of implementing OpenCL support to match our offload support for CUDA-based accelerators. This would not be particularly hard. However, at present, we don't have any demand from grant-funded projects that support our work to do so. We would welcome contributions of code to do this. There's also the possibility that commercial development may lead to this getting implemented.